# Error while Reverse Proxying html files from AWS S3 using Golang

Tags: node.js, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to reverse proxy html files from an S3 bucket, https://test-bucket-a-cloud-guru.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/acloudguru/index.html, as you can see that it is publicly available.

I have the following code in NodeJS which is working fine, I can access the static website at acloudguru.localhost:8080

```
const express = require('express')
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

const app = express()
const PORT = 8080

const BASE_PATH = 'https://test-bucket-a-cloud-guru.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxy()

app.use((req, res) => {
    const hostname = req.hostname;
    const subdomain = hostname.split('.')[0];

    // Custom Domain - DB Query

    const resolvesTo = `${BASE_PATH}/${subdomain}`

    return proxy.web(req, res, { target: resolvesTo, changeOrigin: true })

})

proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    if (url === '/')
        proxyReq.path += 'index.html'

})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Reverse Proxy Running..${PORT}`))
```

but when I'm trying to recreate the same thing using Go's SingleHostReverseProxy, I'm getting access denied errors

Here's my go code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

const (
    port      = ":8080"
    basePath  = "https://test-bucket-a-cloud-guru.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
)

func main() {
    reverseProxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{Scheme: "https", Host: "test-bucket-a-cloud-guru.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"})

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        hostname := strings.Split(r.Host, ":")[0] // Remove port if present
        subdomain := strings.Split(hostname, ".")[0]

        // Custom Domain - DB Query

        targetURL := basePath + "/" + subdomain
        r.URL, _ = url.Parse(targetURL) // Update request URL to the target URL

        reverseProxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    log.Printf("Reverse Proxy Running on port %s...\n", port)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting server: %s", err)
    }
}
```

and the error is:

```
<Error class="hidden">
<link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-сustom-style"/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-theme-changer-style"/>
<Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>
<Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
<RequestId>YKN3P47N6FTVFGFQ</RequestId>
<HostId>JSTTiBcf+Mg2hwlpy0oEjTCOhO7xNcbCAGSBN3dD3WuSVp4OzI8YzQMP6kIN/cm0FqptpR2upAY=</HostId>
</Error>
```

also, it is redirecting my localhost url to https://acloudguru.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/acloudguru

How do I fix this? Please help

Comment: https://test-bucket-a-cloud-guru.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/acloudguru/index.html does not exists now, even if i did, i think this is not the link to access static website.

first setup your S3 bucket's properties for static website hosting in AWS S3 console

after that replace basePath with https://acloudguru.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com or provided in the S3 console.